# Why does my regex not work on input from file.read()?

Tags: python, regex, string, file-io, quotes

I have a section of code that I need to remove from multiple files that starts like this:

```
<?php
//{{56541616
```

and ends like this:

```
//}}18420732
?>
```

where both strings of numbers can be any sequence of letters and numbers (not the same).

I wrote a Python program that will return the entire input string except for this problem string:

```
def removeInsert(text):
    m = re.search(r"<\?php\n\/\/\{\{[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}.*\/\/\}\}[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}\n\?>", text, re.DOTALL)
    return text[:m.start()] + text[m.end():]
```

This program works great when I call it with removeInsert("""[file text]""") -- the triple quotes allow it to be read in as multiline.

I attempted to extend this to open a file and pass the string contents of the file to removeInsert() with this:

```
def fileRW(filename):
    input_file = open(filename, 'r')
    text = input_file.read()
    newText = removeInsert(text)
    ...
```

However, when I run fileRW([input-file]), I get this error:

```
return text[:m.start()] + text[m.end():]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'start'
```

I can confirm that "text" in that last code is actually a string, and does contain the problem code, but it seems that the removeInsert() code doesn't work on this string.  My best guess is that it's related to the triple quoting I do when inputting the string manually into removeInsert().  Perhaps the text that fileRW() passes to removeInsert() is not triple-quoted (I've tried different ways of forcing it to have triple quotes ("\"\"\"" added), but that doesn't work).  I have no idea how to fix this, though, and can't find any information about it in my google searching.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex only uses `\n` for lines.  Your text editor may insert a carriage return and newline combination: `\r\n`.  Try changing `\n` in your regex to `(\r\n|\r|\n)`.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it. I'd thought there might be a newline issue, but couldn't come up with what it would look like.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the `\n` in your regular expressions and open the file as:

```
input_file= open(filename, 'rU')
```

Note the [extra U](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open) in the mode. This will allow your code to work even if used on other operating systems, or given files having “foreign” end-of-line.